# Why does an empty service worker significantly slow down page load speed?

Tags: performance, web, caching, performance-testing, service-worker

A very simple setup.

1. Importing service worker file within `<script>` tag in index.html like so:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/app/static/js/service-worker.js', { scope: '/' });
    });
}
```

2. Service worker itself is empty (1 line):

```
console.log('Successfully Installed Service Worker.');
```

3. After running page load speed tests I get interesting results:

```
                        DOM Interactive    DOM Complete       Load Event End     Number of page loads
no-service-worker       0.232              2.443              2.464              30
with-service-worker     0.343              2.484              2.502              30
```

What gives? How does an empty service worker slow down page load by whopping 120+ milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some browsers will optimize things by detecting when there isn't a `fetch` handler in a service worker and not block navigations on service worker startup. (Chrome is pretty aggressive about this.) Other browsers don't. You don't mention which browser you're testing this on, but I'm not particularly surprised that there's *some* impact.

There's some more background on this topic [in this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBpQlNeq5-o).

Comment: Thanks for a reply. I was running tests in Chrome 81.0.4043.2 Canary. Since my service worker is empty and doesn't register any `fetch` handlers I assume there should be no added overhead from that. I also looked at the talk you referenced but the only thing that I found relatable to my scenario is the service worker startup costs. But this is again confusing. If service worker is empty then why would it add a lag? Maybe those 120ms is the cost of startup of the service worker engine in Chrome?

Comment: Yes, I'd imagine that's the case. Even though the network request shouldn't block on service worker startup (since there's no `fetch` handler), CPU time that could be spent on rendering the page does end up being spent on spinning up the SW.